# Compiz on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: compiz

I cannot get Compiz effects to work on 18.04.2. What all needs to be installed for Compiz to work? I have installed it from synaptic package manager. I am unable to upgrade my graphics driver as none are available.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**, Compiz is not supported by `gnome-shell`, it uses mutter as it compositor—so you can't use compiz effect for now.

There is a possibility though, it seems one of compiz former developer has created [the `libanimation` project](https://github.com/smspillaz/libanimation), reportedly few effect has been added as `gnome-shell` extension.

I suggest you to read this following article → https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/09/wobbly-windows-new-libanimation-linux-library

If you really want to draw full compiz experience, you could use say Ubuntu MATE— compiz works very well with it.